# what can be used to find the sha2 checksum of a file in windows

Tags: windows, checksum, sha2

What is the best method for getting a SHA2 checksum in windows? I'm looking for something equivalent to md5sums-1.2 utility referenced for putty downloads, with more options than just md5. Edit - after more searching it seems only sha1 sha256 sha512 have working programs for anything outside of hashing text. I want to find the sha2 checksum of a file, is this no dice yet due to sha2 recently becoming popular?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [7-zip 15.14 or later](http://www.7-zip.org/) - one of the new features (optionally) adds a hash option to the Windows Explorer context menu, one of which is SHA256 values.

You can use [Jacksum](http://www.jonelo.de/java/jacksum/), a Java program that has a wide variety of hashes for files and even entire directories.

You might be able to use [Gnuwin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) which I believe includes sha1sum and sha256sum.

If you're validating downloads to check for corruption, the [Firefox DownloadThemAll addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) will actually check the hash as part of the download process!