# What File Checksum Integrity Verifier can I use on Windows-8?

Tags: windows-8, checksum

I've downloaded an application.  I would like to make sure that it is what was presented, and there's a checksum to do so.

I'm making some assumptions, but I believe I need a checksum verifier.

I thought this might be useful, since it's from Microsoft:

[Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier tool](http://Microsoft%20File%20Checksum%20Integrity%20Verifier%20tool)
Version:
1.0
File Name:
Windows-KB841290-x86-ENU.exe
Date Published:
8/22/2012
File Size:
117 KB

...and downloading another checksum verifier without being able to check that it's not been hacked, is a chicken-and-egg problem.

But, it appears that doesn't work with Windows 8 (Which may explain why I'm unable to get it to install)

**What should I use (or how should I go about) confirming a checksum for a downloaded installer on Windows-8**

[what can be used to find the sha2 checksum of a file in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919308/what-can-be-used-to-find-the-sha2-checksum-of-a-file-in-windows)

Has one reply with a bunch of 3rd party apps.  Is there no official way to do checksums?

Comment: I use this: http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/

Comment: You should add that as an actual answer so I can select it as the best answer so far.  Still a 3rd party tool, but better than nothing (and looks real light-weight, non-hog, and open-source).  Also, worked on my installation of win-8.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 and 8, open a cmd terminal and type:

```
certutil -hashfile C:\Users\Jane\Downloads\SampleProgramfile.exe MD5
```

It will return something like this -

```
MD5 hash of file C:\Users\Jane\Downloads\SampleProgramfile.exe:
23 a7 50 d9 c8 6a fe 4e 3b 99 f9 87 6a 7c d4 02
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

Check that those numbers match the ones provided by the software author.

Instead of MD5 you can also use SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512.

Microsoft's docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732443(v=ws.11)#BKMK_menu).

Answer (score 1):

There is pre-installed utility, accessible from the command-line (right swipe, search `cmd`), called `CertUtil`, use it like this:

```
CertUtil -hashfile Downloads\Stupid_Program-2.2.2-win64.exe SHA1
```

You can use tab-completion to autofill files and directories.  I know 'SHA1' and 'MD5' are working, and probably others as well.